# How do I turn a string Array into a textview Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a string array as shown below, what is the best way to reformat this to obtain a TextView array

```
public static List<AthenaPanel> getData()  {

    //created an object for ur Drawer recyclerview array
    List<AthenaPanel> data= new ArrayList<>();
    //this is where you would add all your icons for the drawer list
    //arrays of icons
    int[] icons={R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp};

    String[] titles = { "MyQuestions","     MyAnswers","     Calendar","     Setting","     Send FeedBack"};
    //this is our for loop to cycle through the icons and the titles
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        AthenaPanel current=new AthenaPanel();

        //i%().length allows ups to loop over the array any number of times we want to
        current.iconId=icons[i%icons.length];
        current.title=titles[i%titles.length];
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Here is my  class

```
public class AthenaPanel {
int iconId;
String title;
```

}

Comment: You wouldn't-  the question doesn't make sense.  Do you have a layout with a bunch of text views and you want to stick the data in there?  Or do you want to create new TextViews and add them to your layout dynamically?

Comment: I have a bunch of textviews in a seperate xml file and I want to add them into it, that is really what i am asking

Comment: THen you need to do a findViewById on each textview, then call setText on the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve without more details, my thought is that there is a different way to get what you want, but I'm going to answer the question anyway.

In this case I guess you want to generate as many textviews as `AthenaPanel` objects are returned by `getData()`, the best is not to restrict the layout to a determined number of TextViews defined in your xml. Instead, remove all TextView tags from your xml and leave a blank `LinearLayout`
You should create the same number of `TextView` with a base context:

```
public List<TextView> createTextViews(Context context, List<AthenaPanel> athenaPanelList) {
   ArrayList<TextView> textViewList = new ArrayList<>();

   if(athenaPanelList != null && athenaPanelList.size() > 0) {
      for(AthenaPanel athenaPanel : athenaPanelList) {
         TextView textView = new TextView(context);
         textView.setText(athenaPanel.getTitle());
         textViewList.add(textView);
      }
   }

   return textViewList;
}
```

And call that method to add the views to the `LinearLayout`. Let's say a linear layout in your activity:

```
LinearLayout myLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
ArrayList<TextView> textViews = createTextViews(this, getData());
for(TextView textView : textViews){
   myLinearLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

You'll need to specify LayoutParams for the `TextView's` if you don't want them to use the default LayoutParams from the root layout. The LinearLayout can be actually any subclass of `ViewGroup` i.e. FrameLayout, RelativeLayout...

If the only thing you want is to convert that `String` array to TextView Array:

```
String[] titles = { "MyQuestions","     MyAnswers","     Calendar","     Setting","     Send FeedBack"};
TextView[] textViews = new TextView[titles.length];
for(int i=0; i < titles.length; i++){    // I'd suggest to use lenght propery rather than 5 value
   TextView textView = new TextView(context);
   textView.setText(athenaPanel.getTitle());
   textViews[i] = textView;
}
```

Comment: Great Response!Thanks!

Comment: Sorry my bad, that was an accident